# iPhone views programming

Tags: iphone, button, crash

I'm trying to have 2 views in my app, using 2 buttons on my home screen. For each of these buttons I've created a new class and added the following code to my view controller:

**ViewController.h :**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface Gallerie2ViewController : UIViewController {
}
- (IBAction)switch2class1:(id)sender; // 1st button
- (IBAction)switch2class2:(id)sender; // 2nd one
@end
```

**ViewController.m :**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "class1.h"
#import "class2.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)switch2class1:(id)sender
{
    Class1 *Class1view = [[Class1 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:Class1view animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)switch2class2:(id)sender
{
    Class2 *Class2View = [[Class2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:Class2View animated:YES];
}
```

Class1.h/.m has the same content than Class2.h/.m , but when running my app, the 1st button works fine (opens the Class1 view) but the 2nd button crashes the app!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does the log say? in xcode, go to run -> console, then click clear console, and then build and run, and paste the code here after its crashed

Comment: A minor nitpick unrelated to crashing: it looks like Class1 and Class2 are UIViewController subclasses, so it would be less confusing if it read "UIViewController* controller = ..." instead of "Class2 *Class2View = ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, I've checked with the console (thanks Sam Jarman) and found the cause of this issue : one of my classes (Class2) was named List. So it compiled with List.h and List.m but List.h is already defined (probably part of the SDK). It didn't make any error/warning of the conflict at compiling, but well.. i've renamed list.h to cat.h and it works fine now !

Thanks !

Comment: Glad that you resolved the problem so quickly. Go ahead and mark this as the accepted answer. Besides the fact that you will get extra reputation, it helps the community and the site :)